# PHP: Set object properties inside a foreach loop

Tags: php

Is it possible to set property values of an object using a foreach loop?

I mean something equivalent to:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $array[$key] = get_new_value();
}
```

**EDIT:** My example code did nothing, as @YonatanNir and @gandra404 pointed out, so I changed it a little bit so it reflects what I meant

Comment: but you did nothing there.. you took the same keys and values and just assigned it to the same place there were before that...

Comment: When you use `foreach` it must be an `array` to loop through. Rather generate the array the convert it to object.

Comment: you mean doing `$this->$key = $value` maybe ? where `$key` is the name of the property you want to check ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $key => $value) { ... }`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis looks to fit the question indeed...

Comment: @Random, you're right! I didn't know you could use a variable instead of the name of a property! ^_^U

Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop on an array containing properties names and values to set.

For instance, an object which has properties "$var1", "$var2", and "$var3", you can set them this way :

```
$propertiesToSet = array("var1" => "test value 1", 
                         "var2" => "test value 2", 
                         "var3" => "test value 3");
$myObject = new MyClass();
foreach($propertiesToSet as $property => $value) {
    // same as $myObject->var1 = "test value 1";
    $myObject->$property = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this example help at all?

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->prop1 = 1;
$object->prop2 = 2;
foreach ($object as $prop=>$value) {
    $object->$prop = $object->$prop +1;
}
print_r($object);
```

This should output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [prop1] => 2
    [prop2] => 3
)
```

Also, you can do

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->prop1 = 1;
$object->prop2 = 2;
foreach ($object as $prop=>&$value) {
    $value = $value + 1;
}
print_r($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.iterator.php) interface and loop through the array of objects:

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $object->your_property = get_new_value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacked away at this for a few hours and this is what i finally used.  Note the parameters passed by reference in two places. One when you enter the method and the other in the foreach loop.

```
private function encryptIdsFromData(&$data){
    if($data == null)
        return;

    foreach($data as &$item){

        if(isset($item["id"]))
            $item["id"] = $this->encrypt($item["id"]);

        if(is_array($item))
            $this->encryptIdsFromData($item);
            
    }
}
```